# Unable to read property key value from GIT repository using Config Server Services in Steeltoe

Tags: cloud-foundry, asp.net-core-2.1, pcf, configserver, steeltoe

I am not able read property value from git in steeltoe for dot net core 2.1 application.

From my client application, I want to read properties file which is present in Git repository for different environment properties files like foo-development.properties/foo-Production.properties based on environment of the application.

Find my below Code for reading data

**Program.cs:**

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
      WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseCloudFoundryHosting(5000)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(b => b.AddConfigServer(new LoggerFactory().AddConsole(LogLevel.Trace)))
    .AddCloudFoundry()   
    .UseUnityServiceProvider()
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

**Startup Page**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions();
        services.ConfigureConfigServerClientOptions(Configuration);
        services.AddConfiguration(Configuration);
        services.ConfigureCloudFoundryOptions(Configuration);           

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddDiscoveryClient(Configuration);

        //The following setting is tp read config values from json to class
        services.Configure<ConfigSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConfigSettings"));

        // Adds the configuration data POCO configured with data returned from the Spring Cloud Config Server
        services.Configure<ConfigServerData>(Configuration);

        services.AddScoped<ApiExceptionFilter>();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Alcatraz AddUrlLink Service", Version = "v1" });
        });
    }
```

**Controller page**

```
public class HomeController
{
    private IOptionsSnapshot<ConfigServerData> IConfigServerData { get; set; }
    private CloudFoundryServicesOptions CloudFoundryServices { get; set; }
    private CloudFoundryApplicationOptions CloudFoundryApplication { get; set; }
    private IConfigurationRoot Config { get; set; }
    public HomeController(IOptionsSnapshot<ConfigServerData> configServerData, IConfigurationRoot config,
        IOptions<CloudFoundryApplicationOptions> appOptions,
        IOptions<CloudFoundryServicesOptions> servOptions)
    {
        if (configServerData != null)
            IConfigServerData = configServerData;

        // The ASP.NET DI mechanism injects these as well, see
        // public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in Startup class
        if (servOptions != null)
            CloudFoundryServices = servOptions.Value;
        if (appOptions != null)
            CloudFoundryApplication = appOptions.Value;

        _service = service;
        Config = config;
        CreateConfigServerDataViewData();
    }

    private void CreateConfigServerDataViewData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started...");
        // IConfigServerData property is set to a IOptionsSnapshot<ConfigServerData> that has been
        // initialized with the configuration data returned from the Spring Cloud Config Server
        if (IConfigServerData != null && IConfigServerData.Value != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (IConfigServerData != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not Null" + IConfigServerData.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch(System.Exception ex) { }

            var data = IConfigServerData.Value; 

            if (IConfigServerData.Value != null)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Propertis " + data);
                Console.WriteLine("Propertis " + data.foo);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("foo1 " + Config["Foo"]);
            Console.WriteLine("foo2 " + Config["foo"]);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There is no Properties Files available");
        }

    }
}
```

**Class files**

```
public class ConfigServerData
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public string foo { get; set; }

    // Optional data from vault
    public string Vault { get; set; }
}
```

myclient.properties & myclient-development.properties files in Git repository

```
foo: Test
```

I have committed this files in defined git URL. but I'm unable to get message property in my client application.

Kindly please help me on this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this with config server running on PCF or local workstation? Which ConfigServer nuget package are you using?
Do you have any related log entries available?

Comment: Yes.I am running config in PCF. I using below nuget package. Steeltoe.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigServer and Steeltoe.Extensions.Configuration.CloudFoundry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Cloud Config Server on PCF requires interactions to be authorized. In version 2.1 of Steeltoe, that authorization is not performed in Steeltoe.Extensions.ConfigServer*, but is performed in Pivotal.Extensions.ConfigServer*

For your ConfigServer NuGet reference and `using` statement in `program.cs`, change "Steeltoe" to "Pivotal" and you should be all set.

With this change, you can also remove the`.AddCloudFoundry` on `WebHostBuilder` as the Pivotal version of the Cloud Foundry Config Provider will add that for you.